# How can I get the Full URL's being accessed over TCP, on OSX (or linux)

Tags: http, http-proxy, iftop

Is there a way that I can have `iftop` (or some other command) run on my mac (linux also is okay) which will display the exact

- ***http requests*** which are being made, including
- the ***parameters*** being sent

Currently, **iftop** gives me results like this:

[image]

And similarly, **wireshark** gives me alot of information, but none of the http parameters that i need to see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use wireshark, a proxy like tinyproxy or squid or a debugging tool in a browser, chrome has it integrated, Firefox might have it also or it as a plugin called live http header.

Wireshark gets all packets it can even get request from other computers on the same network. You can use filters like
http.request.method == "GET" or http.request.method == "POST"
It gets the information by packet, a request could be longer than a packet, but not likely to happen.
You can also ask on https://ask.wireshark.org. you could also use another packet sniffer like tcp dump.

To get all request from your computer with a proxie you will most likely have to configure it transparent and log all requests.

Debugging tools in browsers get only requests from one page, at least in chrome.

Comment: Will these see all rest requests even the ones sent outside the browser?

Comment: and, also - will i get http parameters etc ? or just the domain name.  my problem right now is that iftop only gives the domain name, and any browswer based tool only monitors requests through the browswer.  I need to monitor traffic sent out by arbitrary programs....

Comment: (updated question to better represent the issue im having).